# VMWare Workstation Pro: "Shut down guest" does "Poweroff" instead

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, acpi

My problem is that VMWare Workstation Pro 12 does not send the ACPI commands to do a clean shutdown of the VM, when I select "Shut down guest" (or resets when I press "Restart guest"). The VM is abruptly powered off (killed) instead, as if I had chosen the "Power off" option.

**Q:** Do I have to manually enable ACPI commands?

Comment: Have you installed VMware tools on the guest?

Comment: Is that required ? I mean, in VirtualBox i can poweroff the vm via acpi without installing guest addons.

Comment: In my experience with VMware, if the tools are not installed, it warns you that it will do a poweroff instead.. but i usually use ESXi, so it might be different.

Comment: VirtualBox supports triggering the ACPI Power Button inside the VM. VMware does not.